# Order preserving injection from countable ordered set into circle.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, order-theory

I know the following result.

> If A is a countable, totally ordered set, then there exists an order preserving injection from $A$ into $R$ (set of reals) with discrete image in R.

Can we replace $R$ by circle $S^1$?

Comment: Is there a particular total order on $S^1$ that you want to consider?

Comment: @GennaroPasquale      I am working with lexicographic order on $S^1$ but can shift to any order.

Comment: Consider the stereo-graphic projection of $\mathbb{R}$ on to $S^1$ and it induces a natural order on $S^1\setminus\{N\}.$ Hoewver since $S^1$ is compact, there can be a limit point in the image of order preserving injection.

Comment: @Bumblebee and what about this one point $N$?

Comment: @ersh: [Check this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection#First_formulation)

Comment: @Bumblebee Stereographic projection is an injection into $S^1-\{N\}$ not into $S^1$.

Comment: @ersh: As I said it induces an order on $S^1\setminus\{N\}$ and you can declare the north pole to be largest (or smallest) element to extent this order to $S^1.$ Also nothing happens to injectivity as we enlarge the co-domain of a function.

Comment: @ersh What is the lexicographic order on $S^1$? Usually the lexicographic order is considered on a product of ordered sets. Do you mean the order on $S^1$ induced by the lexicographic order on $\mathbb{R}^2$ when you embed $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the unit circle? If you "can shift to any order", then why not just put $S^1$ in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$ and take the order on $\mathbb{R}$? Then you get a trivial positive answer to your question.